# get value of jQuery selectmenu and run javascript onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkservice() {
        var val = document.getElementById("select").value;
        if (!!val) {
            document.getElementById("okservice").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("okservice").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
     $( "#select" ).selectmenu();
});
```

And HTML

```
<td class="option">
    <select name="service" id="select" onchange="checkservice()">
          <option value>Select Please</option>
          <option value="1">Repair</option>
          <option value="2">Destroy</option>
    </select>
</td>
        <td id="okservice">
        </td>
```

And I need to get the value of the selectmenu and run the javascript to change background of #okservice

I can't find out where is the problem.
Could anybody help me, please?

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of the selected menu :

```
$("#select").val();
```

and to change the background color , this code may help you :

```
 function checkservice() 
    {
        var val = document.getElementById("select").value;
        if (!!val) 
        {
            $("#okservice").css("background","green");
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $("#okservice").css("background","red");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see that the "onchange" parameter on <select> doesn't work when I'm using jquery ui selectmenu, so I can't even launch the function. :-/

Comment: remove onchange="checkservice()" and try **<script>** _$("#select").change(function(){ checkservice(); });_ **</script>**

Comment: Doesn't work for me :-( I tried running alert("xxx"); in checkservice() to check if it works, but it doesn't

Comment: Put your code on jsFiddle so that I can correct it for you

Answer (score 0):

Remove onchange() from html. And Create proper Html like below provide. Depending upon your design and requirements.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> 
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:- using **value** you can get result

```
function checkservice() {
        var val = document.getElementById("select").value;
        if (val) {
            document.getElementById("okservice").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("okservice").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Jquery:-

```
   $(function() {
    $("#select").change(function() {
    checkservice();
   });
     $( "#select" ).selectmenu();
});
```